# python: Compare Dictionaries to return keyError on missing item

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to compare two dictionaries with the desired outcome being a KeyError that identifies the Key that is missing.

this is what i currently have:

```
d1 = {'lion': 10.0}
d2 = {'lion': 10, 'tiger': 3}

def calc_test(d1, d2):
    if set(d2) <= set(d1) == True:
        pass
    else:
        raise KeyError(set(d2))

 
calc_test(d1,d2)
```

if you run this though it gives the output of the entire dictionary:

> KeyError: {'lion', 'tiger'}

what i'm seeking is an output that only shows the missing key:

> KeyError: {'tiger'}

Comment: Is this for keys that are in `d2`, but not in `d1`?

Comment: `raise KeyError(set(d1.keys())-set(d2.keys())) if (set(d1.keys())-set(d2.keys())) else True` Why you are not using this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the keys in `d2` are in `d1`:

```
def calc_test(d1, d2):
    s = []
    for i in d2:
        if i not in d1:
            s.append(i)
    if s:
        raise(KeyError(s))
```

```
# Raises
KeyError: ['tiger']
```

---

Note that this will not work if there is a key in `d1` that is not in `d2`

Although it's larger in length, it's efficient in time and space complexity.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using set, there is a simple function called `symmetric_difference` for finding the uncommon values in two sets.

`set(d2).symmetric_difference(set(d1))`

which will give you the result:
`{'tiger'}`

So you can modify you function like this:

```
d1 = {'lion': 10.0}
d2 = {'lion': 10, 'tiger': 3}

def calc_test(d1, d2):
    uncommon_items = set(d2).symmetric_difference(set(d1))
    if len(uncommon_items) > 0:
        raise KeyError(uncommon_items)

calc_test(d1, d2)
```

Comment: `set(d2).symmetric_difference(d1)` This will also work.

Answer (score 2):

Try `difference`:

```
d1 = {'lion': 10.0}
d2 = {'lion': 10, 'tiger': 3}

def calc_test(d1, d2):
    if set(d2) <= set(d1) == True:
        pass
    else:
        raise KeyError(set(d2).difference(set(d1)))

 
calc_test(d1,d2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the difference operator, `set(d2)-set(d1)`.

```
d1 = {'lion': 10.0}
d2 = {'lion': 10, 'tiger': 3}

def calc_test(d1, d2):
    if set(d2) <= set(d1) == True:
        pass
    else:
        raise KeyError(set(d2)-set(d1))

try:
    calc_test(d1,d2)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

This will show the keys in `d2` that are not in `d1`.